# Changing image src outside div running jquery cycle

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, cycle

I am building a wordpress site using jQuery with cycle plugin to cycle through some posts.

I have an image used as a full background, with this css:

```
  img.bg {
        /* Set rules to fill background */
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;

        /* Set up proportionate scaling */
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        /* Set up positioning */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        img.bg {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -512px; }
    }
```

I have inserted the first image attachment url into the img.bg with a javascript from the loop. However, this understandably only works once, at page load.

This is the javascript:

```
$(function () {
$('.bg').attr('src', '<?php get_image_url(); ?>');
});
```

What I need, I guess is to fire off the script with each iteration of the cycle script, because the source shows that the get_image_url() function supplies the script with the unique url in each article div. 
In the end, I even want some navigation buttons to move back and forth, switching the posts and the background simultanuously.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, I use `$(".bg").prependTo(document.body);` to get the background images out of the article div, and then starting the cycle. This works, although some more problems might mount on the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `cycle`'s next iteration function or using `setInterval`.

```
function changeImg()
{
    $('.bg').attr('src', '<?php get_image_url(); ?>');
}
setInterval("changeImg()", 1000);
```

Hope this helps. But still, you would get output only once, when you execute the `get_image_url();`.

Comment: Thanx alot!
I am just a novice really, doing mostly copy and paste.
But I think all the necessary info has reached the client, so there is really no need to execute the get_image_url() more times. I only have to execute the script 
$(function () {
$('.bg').attr('src', 'http://thecorrectimage1.jpg');
});
for each post showing in the cycle script. 
Guess I might need this explained in some detail to understand.